# Adding thousands of product numbers as keywords

Tags: seo, keywords

I am building an AngularJS site for my client who sells commercial wholesale parts.

He would like the product numbers for all ~4,000 of his items to be searchable on Google; that way he is shown in search results of people looking for those items.

What would be the best way to achieve this? He has asked me to include a massive table on our Products page.

If I were to make a product search form that matched a user query for a part number to what we have available, this wouldn't help right? I assume that only static content is used as keywords.

Comment: Google finds keywords within the content and not the queries. Also you should be aware that 4,000 individual pages with thin content is a one way ticket to Panda land. You will need to add unique or manufacturer descriptions on those pages otherwise those pages will not be indexed.

Comment: "a massive table" - If that is the only place the product numbers appear then that will be the page that is returned in the SERPs when someone searches for that product code (if indeed that page does get indexed) - but is that really a desirable landing page for the user?!

Comment: @SimonHayter maybe I was unclear. He doesn't want each item on a separate page, he wants one page with a table showing all the item names / numbers.

Comment: Don't the items that are being sold have their own separate pages? The "product number" should be on the page next to the item that is being sold? By all means have an index (table) of product numbers but these should link directly to the product page that also includes this number. The product page is the preferred landing page from the SERPs.

Comment: You will not rank for 4000 search terms unless these numbers appear nowhere else on the net in similar format.

Comment: The website is a for a wholesale distributor of hardware parts - such as screws, bolts, fasteners, etcetera. Theres not enough information for each item to have its on distinct item page. My client is hoping that if an established company (whom already knows what products they need) searches for that part number, he shows as a result.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

> He would like the product numbers for all ~4,000 of his items to be searchable on Google; that way he is shown in search results of people looking for those items. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Numbers aren't appealing to a generic visitor because they don't look for a product number when they want to buy a product unless the visitor's friend  found the product by number and told the visitor to search by number.

Because of this, you need to try to index your products by useful names. For example, if you're selling small bolts, you can make a page and title it "1 inch steel bolt" and make a wonderful description in a few paragraphs about it with an option at the end to order it so that guests can understand what you are trying to sell and why it is worth selling it. That is more appealing to guests than if you just title the item as "2489249" or something like that.

Of course I would not search for a random number if I wanted a product unless I was looking for specific numerical birthday candles in which case I'd specify a single number.

Comment: While generally I'd absolutely agree with that argument, these are wholesale hardware parts where a manufacturer of lets say airplanes might order X quantity of bolt #012401 and Y quantity of fastener #565122. Think of it like an order form that a store restocking manager would fill out with items they already know by product number. In this event, they might source the parts online by part # and my client is hoping to be shown on the search engine rankings in hope of become the distributor.

Comment: But often people won't automatically know order codes without some kind of reference such as a store flyer or a friend. People know products best by name

Comment: Sorry, are you an expert in this industry? You keep arguing as if what I am saying is false, which provides zero benefit to answering my question. I have told you that my client's customers order based on a predefined set of product numbers that I am trying to SEO.